# Verticaly Center Align Element with pull-right Class in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

### HTML Code:

```
<h5>
<span style="vertical-align:central"><i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right" style="font-size: x-large;"></i></span>
<img src="/myimage.jpg" /><span style="padding-left: 1em"></span>
<b>  Item 1 - Item 2 </b> <br />
<span style="font-size:small;padding-left:4em">StatusColourCode</span>
</h5>
```

How can I make the span element with the class `fa fa-angle-right pull-right` vertically center, based on `h5` element?

I tried `style="vertical-align:central"` but doesn't work.

### Screenshoot:

[image]

Comment: Does the row has a fixed height? If so, doesn't `line-height: [xx]px` solve your problem?

Comment: @JoaquínO It's a ASP.NET Repeater control and the content is inside the ItemTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` should be `middle` not `central` and should be applied to image

Comment: hi @Marko! Thank you for the reply. I set it to middle but still no luck.

Comment: @chamara to image ?

Comment: @chamara well you didn't say that it should be verticaly centred to div  :) ok that changes situation a bit, could you provide minimum code to replicate your dive with image and that arrow in jsfiddle ?

Comment: Actually it's not a plain DIV. It's a ASP.NET Repeater control and it's rendered as a div. So, I may not be able to replicate this on jsfiddle. :(

Answer (score 0):

To vertically center an element in a div, you can't `use vertical-align:middle` unless the div is a table. To do so, you just CSS3 Transform and CSS Positioning. Here's the code :

```
div{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding line-height **line-height:3em**

```
<h5>
<span style="vertical-align:central"><i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right" style="font-size: x-large;line-height:3em"></i></span>
<img src="/myimage.jpg" /><span style="padding-left: 1em"></span>
<b>  Item 1 - Item 2 </b> <br />
<span style="font-size:small;padding-left:4em">StatusColourCode</span>
</h5>
```